# How can I validate the amount of times a character appears in an input string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation, while-loop

For instance: I want my users to enter 5 numbers separated by commas...

If i wanna make sure that a comma (,) only appears 4 times or else they'll have to re-enter their string again, how do I go about validating that?

example question: "Please enter 5 numbers, all separated by commas - "

bad answer: 2,3 or 4,5,6,7,8,9

good answer: 2,3,4,5,6 (4 commas, 5 numbers)

my thought is I should be using regex. If anyone has any other ideas, please share. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a regex is a reasonable plan here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't 'need' a regular expression, this can be done with basic Python functions:

```
answer = '2,3,4,5,6'

split_answer = answer.split(',')
if len(split_answer) == 5 and all(number.strip().isdigit() for number in split_answer):
    print ('good answer')
else:
    print ('bad answer')
```

With the line `answer.split(',')` you test the number of elements that remain after splitting on a single comma; with `all(..)` you test each of these elements for consisting only out of digits. The `strip` inside it is to make sure surrounding whitespace gets removed first.

Comment: Good answer but I feel like this would only validate it as a correct answer only if all the input numbers were single digit. For instance what if the user input 1,2,35,6,7? That would come back as a length greater than 5 thus, rendering it a bad answer.

Comment: @ZachariaSalad: no, that does not happen. Your sample input also returns '5'. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match exactly 5 comma separated numbers,

```
^\d+(?:,\d+){4}$
```

Here,

- `^` --> Start of input
- `\d+` --> Matches one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+){4}` --> Matches a comma followed by one or more digits and this pattern exactly 4 times.
- `$` --> End of input

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXBnQG/1)**

In case your input might have optional spaces, you can use following regex.

```
^\s*\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*){4}$
```

Here is python sample code,

```
import re
arr = ['2,3','4,5,6,7,8,9','2,3,4,5,6']
for s in arr:
 if re.match(r'^\d+(?:,\d+){4}$', s): 
  print(s + ' --> Match')
 else: 
  print(s + ' --> Do not Match')
```

Which prints,

```
2,3 --> Do not Match
4,5,6,7,8,9 --> Do not Match
2,3,4,5,6 --> Match
```

Comment: There is no lookahead. Where do you see that?

Answer (score 0):

A very pythonic way would be to:

```
sample = "1,3,23,12,"
if(len(sample.split(","))<sample.count(",")) and sample.count(",") ==4:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The above method would counter the error if a character is missing after a separator.